# randomly generating and controlling the value for sqlite database in PHP

Tags: php, sqlite

hi guys i got this sqlite database which has only one 1 row called revenue_value and it has 2000 value. Lets say i click generate value button and generates 12 random number and i know `rand` will randomly generate values but all i want to know is can i control that randomness value for example - 2000 is the base value but at the end it has to end up with 20% higher than 2000 but in between value can go down or up.

i got the table working
data.php

```
<?php
try
{
$db = new PDO('sqlite:randvalue.sqlite');
$db->exec("CREATE TABLE company (revenue_value INTEGER PRIMARY KEY)");

$db->exec("INSERT INTO company(revenue_value) VALUES ('2000')");

print "<table border=1>";
print "<tr><td>value</td></tr>";
$result = $db->query('SELECT * FROM company');

foreach($result as $row)
{
    print "<tr><td>".$row['revenue_value']."</td></tr>";
}
print "</table>";

$db = NULL;

}

catch(PDOException $e)
{
    print 'Exception : '.$e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

and the rest of the code is ajax.js which will echo it to index.php

any ideas guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Break down the problem into smaller parts, apply logic. The way you've asked the question implies you're trying to solve the whole thing at once. eg: Sqlite has nothing to do with the actual problem that's holding you back.

You have two values, 2000 and 2400 [2000 + 20%] and you want to generate 10 random values between those numbers.

```
$start = 2000;
$end = 2000 * 1.2;
$numbers = array($start);

for($i=0; $i<10; $i++) {
  $numbers[] = rand($start, $end);
}
$numbers[] = $end;
```

*Then* loop through `$numbers` and insert them into your database.

**edit**

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO company (revenue_value) VALUES (?)');
foreach($numbers as $number) {
  $stmt->execute(array($number));
}
```

Comment: i wish i knew how to use loop properly. hmmm let me do some thinking on using loop to insert.

Comment: thank you. I spend all day to figure this out now i wish i paid attention to loop in class and again thanks :)